# Allow caller to supply LINQ predicate without knowing value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

We're using LINQ to EF and I'm trying to write a `CachingRepository` class that will simplify the pattern of caching retrieved entities in memory for the lifecycle of a single repository instance. The trick is that I want to be able to specify the property by which the entities are cached as a parameter to the constructor:

```cs
public class CachingRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TEntity> _cache
        = new Dictionary<TKey, TEntity>();

    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> _repository;

    private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> _selector;

    public CachingRepository(IRepository<TEntity> repository, Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> entityKeySelector)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _selector = entityKeySelector;
    }
}
```

(The existing `IRepository` implementation is pretty straightforward). So if someone wants to create a CachingRepository that caches per `Employee.BadgeCode` for example (where `BadgeCode` is a string), they could take an existing Employee repository and:

```cs
var cacheRepo = new CachingRepository(employeeRepo, (Employee) emp => emp.BadgeCode);
```

Here's the meat of the repository, where the cache has missed and I want to retrieve from the database:

```cs
    private TEntity GetFromStore(TKey key)
    {
        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);

        var paramName = _selector.Parameters[0].Name;

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, paramName);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                _selector.Body,
                Expression.Constant(key)
                )
            , parameter);

        return _repository.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
    }
```

However, in trying to run the above example I get an exception

> The parameter 'emp' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong in simply passing `_selector.Body` to the `Equal` expression, but how should I do it? It seems like I need to have `parameter` "get into" my `_selector` expression but I'm not sure how to do that.

I realize that I could just pluck the property name from the selector in the constructor, and use something like `Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName)` instead, but it'd be nice to be able to pass more complex selector expressions besides simple property selectors. (Not to mention I'd like to understand why this isn't working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors occurs because `_selector.Body` is trying to access the 'emp' parameter, and that doesn't exist in the `lambda` you're creating. To fix it you should just be able to reuse `_selector.Parameters[0]` for the parameter you pass to `Expression.Lambda` instead of creating the new `parameter` `ParameterExpression`:

```
private TEntity GetFromStore(TKey key)
{
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            _selector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(key)
            )
        , _selector.Parameters[0]);

    return _repository.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
}
```

Comment: Aaaah yes that did it, thanks! That makes a lot of sense now that I see it... I guess I was assuming LINQ "figured it out" based on just the parameter name but it has to be the _same_ parameter instance.

Comment: It does, yeah - the exact same object. You're welcome, happy to help! :)